# Use cases for Ruby's EOB construct

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, heredoc

I recently came across the Ruby `EOB` / `-EOB` construct within this context (from the Ruby [id3 library](https://github.com/tilo/ID3/blob/master/lib/id3.rb#L1220)) :

```
def initialize(...)
  # ...

  instance_eval <<-EOB
    class << self

      def parse
        # ...
        # Method code
        # ...
      end   
  EOB 
  self.parse # now we're using the just defined parsing routine

  # ...
end
```

I understand that the code is used to generate a method on the fly, yet I would like to know if it would be possible to use the `EOB` snippet within a method. I would like to write a method which generates some other method code , which is to be included in yet another class. This sounds a bit confusing, I'll try to illustrate my intention with some simplified code samples :

```
# This class reads the code of another 
# Ruby class and injects some methods
class ReadAndInject

  # The method which defines another method
  def get_code_to_be_injected
    "\tdef self.foo\n"+
    "\t\tputs 'bar'\n"+
    "\tend\n"
  end

  # Main entry point, reads a generated Ruby Class
  # and injects specific methods within it
  def read_and_inject

    # Assume placeholder for currently read line,
    # add the generated code within
    current_line += "\n#{get_code_to_be_injected}"
  end

end # class ReadAndInject
```

This would work, since the method to be injected is added correctly. Yet I was wondering if using the `EOB` construct would yield some advantages (e.g. better visibility of the code, since no cumbersome tabs or string concatenations would have to be added.

To conclude, is this a good use case for `EOB` ? 
It seems like a shady yet powerful construct, I've [ducked](http://duckduckgo.com) it, googled and stackoverflow'd it yet no significant code samples other than [one from RubyCocoa](http://opensource.apple.com/source/RubyCocoa/RubyCocoa-57/RubyCocoa/framework/tool/rubycocoa/bin/rubycocoa) were returned. I've only recently started to use meta constructs in Ruby, so please be gentle :-)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The EOB is just another way to define a String. In your _get_code_to_be_injected_ are no newlines (or ; to separate the commands), so I would expect an error, because it is no valid ruby. To answer your question: Yes, I would use this kind of String definition.

Comment: @knut, yes exactly. Can be called line oriented string literals, or HERE documents: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc

Comment: @knut True, forgot to add the newlines, editing. Ok, so it's just another way of defining a multi-line String. You can add it as an answer if you wish. Thanks for the swift input!

Comment: @miku Thanks for the documentation reference, good stuff!

Comment: You may find a good example in the mustache_rails3 gem (see.: [mustache_rails3 gem](https://github.com/dfltr/mustache_rails3/blob/master/lib/mustache_rails.rb)).

Comment: @Dr1Ku Searching for [<<EOT](http://google.com/codesearch?q=%3C%3C%5BA-Z%5D%2B%24) gives good results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called ["here documents"](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc), which are supported by several languages, and allow you to make a multi-line string. You can actually use any delimiter, not just EOB. Ruby has some extra features for heredocs: for example, the `-` in `<<-EOB` allows you to indent the delimiter.

You might use it like this:

```
def code_to_be_injected
  <<-EOS
    def self.foo
      puts 'bar'
    end
  EOS
end
```

Some additional features in Ruby:

```
myvar = 42
<<EOS
variable: #{myvar}
EOS #=> "variable: 42"

<<'EOS'
variable: #{myvar}
EOS #=> "variable: #{myvar}"

print <<A, <<B
This will appear first
A
and this second
B
```

Comment: Edited my answer to include some more exciting examples!

Comment: Exciting? You need to get out more :)

Comment: What are you talking about? I swear I haven't been sitting inside on my computer all weekend. :P  (Related: curse you, daily reputation cap!)

Comment: @jtbandes Damn, there is such a thing? Does the extra reputation get added afterwards? Would be a bummer if it didn't. Most exquisite usage of 42 above! ..and ditto, though I've been out for some errands ^_^